# Why should we map the node_modules to volumes when dockerize node app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I wonder why mapping the node_module to it own volume considered as a best practice for some people. here's the sample docker compose

```
services:
  app:
    ...:
    ...: ...
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

When I'm removing the `/app/node_modules` volumes, my app works just fine, what's going on here?

Comment: It stores the application's library dependencies in an _anonymous volume_, causing it to have a different set of libraries from its image and to ignore changes in the `package.json` file.  I'd recommend deleting this `volumes:` block entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you map your working directory to `/app`. This mapping hides everything under that directory in the image - including `/app/node_modules`.

In your Dockerfile, you've installed a bunch of node modules in `/app/node_modules` and they're now hidden.

To make them visible again, you map 'nothing' to `/app/node_modules` and now the node modules installed in the image are visible again.

So you end up with a container where `/app` contains the content of your current directory on the host, but `/app/node_modules` contains the content of the image. Which is what you want.

The reason your app works when you remove the `/app/node_modules` mapping is that you also have the modules installed on the host machine. So the mapping of your current directory to `/app` also maps the `node_modules` under your current directory.

Comment: `/app/node_modules` contains the contents of an anonymous volume.  The _first_ time that volume is mounted, Docker copies the image contents into the volume, so this apparently works until you change `package.json`.  It seems to be a common misperception that it "passes through" the contents from the image, but it doesn't really.